# Using hangfire BackgroundJob.Schedule with httpclientfactory DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, httpclient, hangfire, httpclientfactory

I have an api which is using the httpclientfactory to create different typed httpclients using services.addhttpclient<>(). I've started to integrate hangfire with my service due to long running jobs. Everything was working fine until I tried to use Hangfires schdule method "BackgroundJob.Schedule". It starts up, schedules the task but when it tries to execute the code I get:

`"Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' while attempting to activate 'BackupApi.BackupApiService'."`

When trying to use Enqueue method it works without problem. Kinda lost atm, all help much appreciated.  My guess is that somehow when the task has scheduled the dependencies is lost when hangfire later tries to use:

```
using BackupApi;

var backupApiService = Activate<BackupApiService>();
await backupApiService.AdhocBackup("BlurredServername");
```

`Startup.cs`

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHttpClient<IBackupApiService, BackupApiService>()
                .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(handler =>
                    new HttpClientHandler
                    {
                        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; }

                    });
            services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
                .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
                .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
                .UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection"), new SqlServerStorageOptions
                {
                    SchemaName = "BackupApi",
                    CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                    UsePageLocksOnDequeue = true,
                    DisableGlobalLocks = true
                }));

            services.Configure<ConnectionInfo>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            //services.AddTransient<IBackupApiService, BackupApiService>()

            var section = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings");

            services.AddHttpClient<DSDClient>()
                .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(handler =>
                    new HttpClientHandler
                    {
                        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                            section["Username"],
                            section["Password"],
                            "blurredomain"),

                        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; }

                    });
            services.AddHangfireServer();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
                //.AddViewComponentsAsServices();


        }
```

`BackupApiService.cs`

```
    public class BackupApiService : IBackupApiService
    {
        public HttpClient _netclient { get; }
        private static IOptions<ConnectionInfo> _config;
        public DSDClient _dsdclient { get; }

        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public BackupApiService(IOptions<ConnectionInfo> config, HttpClient netclient, DSDClient dsdclient, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _config = config;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _dsdclient = dsdclient;


            _netclient = netclient;
            _netclient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 30);
            _netclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            _netclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", _config.Value.NetworkerConnectionString);
            _netclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        }

public async Task<string> AdhocBackup(string ServerName)
        {
            ....
        }
```

`BackupApiV1Controller`

```
    public class BackupApiV1Controller : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IBackupApiService _backupApiService;

        public BackupApiV1Controller(IBackupApiService backupApiService)
        {
            _backupApiService = backupApiService;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("StartDateBackup/")]
        public IActionResult StartDateBackup([FromBody] ServerSchedule serverSchedule)
        {

            var resp = BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => _backupApiService.AdhocBackup(serverSchedule.Servername), serverSchedule.Date);

            return Ok();
       }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("StartAdhocBackup/")]
        public IActionResult StartAdhocBackup([FromBody] Server server)
        {

            var resp = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => _backupApiService.AdhocBackup(server.Servername));

            return Ok(resp);


        }
```

Comment: Someone directed me to the correct solution.. however I can't find who did it so I can't credit him/her. 

> The solution was to use the Interface when triggering the method: `<IBackupApiService>`

`var resp = BackgroundJob.Schedule<IBackupApiService>(service => _backupApiService.AdhocBackup(serverSchedule.Servername), serverSchedule.Date);`

The solution was to use the Interface when triggering the method.

var resp = BackgroundJob.Schedule(service => _backupApiService.AdhocBackup(serverSchedule.Servername), serverSchedule.Date);